# Red dot for review queues doesn't go away

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I've been having this issue for a while -- nothing in my review queues, but the red notification dot is there:

[image]

Over on meta.stackexchange.com I found a post discussing the issue: [Experiment: Review-needed indicator logic for sites that sometimes have empty queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304445/346823)

@JonEricson recommended I post here and ping them there to bring attention to the problem.

Wondering if anyone else is having this issue, and what can be done about it?

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that when you handle all the tasks available, you'll get the indicator after an hour if those items haven't been addressed. One option is to extend the grace period to, say, 2 hours. That'll reduce the time people see the indicator, but might also make the queues less responsive.

Another option is to turn on the ["danger" threshold algorithm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly). It'd give us flexibility to adjust the thresholds at the cost of people seeing the indicator when there are active tasks. On some sites, the result would be posts waiting indefinitely for review.

I'm not advocating either solution, but those are pretty much the options at the moment.

Comment: I've read some of the meta posts on this but there's something I'm still not understanding... *I think the problem is that when you handle all the tasks available, you'll get the indicator after an hour if those items haven't been addressed.* After I handle tasks, someone else also needs to address them? So the same task is both completed by me, and yet still pending? Is there no way to tie the red dot to whether or not there's anything I am *able* to review?

Comment: @LShaver: The difficulty is that it's expensive to calculate the number of review tasks each user has available. If we could calculate the exact number, we'd just display the number rather than the indicator. The previous version displayed an _aproximation_ which wasn't exactly ideal either. The advantage we have now is that we can adjust the triggers.

Comment: @JonEricson But the reviews page itself will give you an exact number. Isn't the issue just caching the number so it doesn't have to recalculate it if you don't visit the queues? If it was me I'd cache it in local storage and update it via ajax. Then it can be accurately clear etc based on when the user actually visits the queues.